# xCode, iOS, cocoa - realize application with login page

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, authorization

I want to realize application with login page.

I've got the separate authorization page based on UIViewController with xib file, which user should see first when app loaded and I've got main application based on UITabBarController in MainStoryboard.storyboard, where user should redirect after success login.

To launch app with the login page I do in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

        NewUserViewController *controller = [[NewUserViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController = controller;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

How can I switch to UITabBarController from NewUserViewController after success login?

I try to (in NewUserViewController.m)

```
MainTabBarViewController *myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

If you can offer another structure of this app I will happy!

I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push to the tab bar controller because its not embedded in a navigation controller. I think a better structure is to make the tab bar controller the root controller of the window, then present your login controller modally from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab. If the login is successful, just dismiss the login controller, and your ready to go. If the login fails, present another view explaining to the user what happened, and go back to the login controller for another try.

Comment: Another words. 

You offer launch the app with UITabBarController and in - (void)viewDidLoad method (UITabBarController.m) just launch my authorization page based on UIViewController with xib file over the UITabBarController. Good idea! I'll try, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov, you probably need to do it in viewDidAppear. You might get an error about trying to present a view controller while another one is being presented in viewDidLoad.

Comment: NewUserViewController *controller = [[NewUserViewController alloc] init];[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: I wrote this in viewDidAppea in UITabBarController class but nothing happen

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller? Even if you do, you should present it from the controller that's on screen, not the navigation controller. So, [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]. Notice that I use presentViewController:animated:completion:. The one you used is depreciated.

Comment: I've got the error: Warning: Attempt to present <NewUserViewController: 0x8561fd0> on <MainTabBarViewController: 0x7464670> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov, how did the current view controller (the one that's self) get on screen? It's hard to diagnose your problem without knowing the structure of your app.

Comment: I understand You.
In storyboard I've got "Tab Bar View Controller"(MainTabBarViewController) as "Initial View Controller" and  separate authorization page based on UIViewController with xib file (not in storyboard) Can I use in "Tab Bar View Controller"(MainTabBarViewController) [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]; where NewUserViewController *controller = [[NewUserViewController alloc] init]; - separate authorization page based on UIViewController with xib file (not in storyboard)

Comment: I don't know if that will work. I still don't know what view controller you have on screen when you try to present the view controller.

Comment: ok... the code work fine if it run, for example, at button's click event, but it doesn't if it run in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated or -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated events just error: Warning: Attempt to present <NewUserViewController: 0x85c6050> on <UITabBarController: 0x836fde0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov, yes that's too early, I said to use viewDidAppear.